# oracle sql Time to Resolve Calculation

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a question and hopefully someone can help, because i have been stuck on this for a long time.

I have a column with remaining minutes for a task to expire and i want to calculate when this task will expire within the business days timeframe starting from the current sysdate day lets say weekdays from 09:00 to 17:00.

```
| Task No   | Minutes Remaining | Expiration date  |
| Task1     | 1800              | 27-10-16 9:45 AM |
| Task2     | 3400              | 28-10-16 9:45 AM |
| Task3     | 400               | 29-10-16 9:45 AM |
| Task4     | 180               | 30-10-16 9:45 AM |
| Task5     | 8400              | 31-10-16 9:45 AM |
| Task6     | 5000              | 1-11-16 9:45 AM  |
```

Comment: Please provide some sample input data and what you're expecting the results to be.

Comment: Please update your question with the extra information. Remember that we can't see your database or your requirements, so you need to provide as much information as possible to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: No, you need to edit your question (if you look at your question, underneath the `sql` and `oracle11g` tags, you'll see `share  edit  close  flag` - click on `edit`) and add the extra information there. That way, you can format it better.

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: `sysdate + interval '1' minute * minutes_remaining` will give you the expiration date. You need to adjust that result for your business hours

Comment: It would help if your expiration date column accurately reflected the date and time you expect the tasks to end based on their remaining minutes. How can something starting at 9am end at 9:45 if the remaining minutes ends with a 0?!

Comment: @Boneist you are right the expiration date is not what i expect because its not possible since sysdate changes all the time (it was just an example of the format).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Thank you for your answer but i know that already, what i need is how to do the adjustment for the business hours

Comment: You want it from the current time, not the beginning of the current day? Is there something constantly updating the remaining minutes for each task row?

Comment: yes the current time up to the end of bussiness day at 17:00 and the minutes remaining change usually decrease for every minute the task is active (there is a flag active or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this was a fun problem. To summarize: You are given a date (which in Oracle always includes the time-of-day) from which you start measurement, and an initial duration in minutes. You need to find the expiration date (meaning date and time-of-day as always), which is calculated by adding the duration in minutes to the "clock-starting" date, but the clock should only run during business hours - 9 to 17, Monday to Friday only (not on weekends).

I assume if the "minutes remaining" is 0, then the expiration should be the same as the "clock-starting" date if it falls within work hours, or 9 am on the next work day otherwise.

To understand the solution, let's break it down in two parts. First let's consider a very special case: the "clock starts" on a Monday at 9 am. Then break down minutes remaining into an integer multiple of 2400 (5*8*60 = 2400 minutes in a full work week), plus an integer multiple of 480 from what's left (480 minutes to a work day), plus whatever is left, if anything. Then: the expiration date is the "clock-starting" date, plus however many weeks, plus however many whole days (between 0 and 4), plus the remaining minutes. One exceptional case here: if the "minutes remaining" is an exact multiple of 480 minutes, then expiration is at 5 pm on a certain work day, and not 9 am on the next work day. This requires special handling in the formula. All this is done in the outer query (at the bottom of the solution below).

Then we need to reduce the general case to this special case. This is done in the subquery `prep` in the solution. I simply increase the "minutes remaining" by the work minutes elapsed from 9 am on Monday at the beginning of the week. This is a relatively simple computation. Note that if the "clock starting" date is after 5 pm on a Friday (or any time on Saturday or Sunday), I must add exactly 2400 minutes, a full work week.

In the solution, I show a variety of "clock starting" dates, `dt`, and minutes remaining, `rm`. I tested a variety of situations, and I think the solution is correct, but you may want to test on more data (other situations I didn't include in the tests).

```
with
     inputs ( task, min_rem, dt ) as (
 select 'Task1', 1800, to_date('27-10-16 9:45 AM', 'dd-mm-yy hh:mi AM') from dual union all
 select 'Task2', 3400, to_date('28-10-16 9:45 AM', 'dd-mm-yy hh:mi AM') from dual union all
 select 'Task3',  400, to_date('29-10-16 3:45 AM', 'dd-mm-yy hh:mi AM') from dual union all
 select 'Task4',  180, to_date('30-10-16 9:45 AM', 'dd-mm-yy hh:mi AM') from dual union all
 select 'Task5', 8400, to_date('31-10-16 9:45 PM', 'dd-mm-yy hh:mi AM') from dual union all
 select 'Task6', 5000, to_date('01-11-16 5:00 PM', 'dd-mm-yy hh:mi AM') from dual union all
 select 'Task7',    0, to_date('01-12-16 5:00 PM', 'dd-mm-yy hh:mi PM') from dual
     ), 
     prep ( task, min_rem, dt, adj_min, adj_dt ) as (
       select task, min_rem, dt,
              min_rem + case when dt > trunc(dt, 'iw') + 5 + 17/24 then 2400
                             else (trunc(dt) - trunc(dt, 'iw')) * 480 +
                                   least(480, greatest(0, 1440 * (dt - trunc(dt) - 9/24)))
                        end,
              trunc(dt, 'iw') + 9/24
     from inputs
     )
select task, min_rem, dt,
       adj_dt + 7 * trunc(adj_min / 2400)
              + case when adj_min/480 = trunc(adj_min/480)
                          then mod(adj_min, 2400) / 480 - 1 + 8/24
                     else trunc(mod(adj_min, 2400) / 480) + mod(adj_min, 480) / 1440
                end as expiration
from   prep
order by task
;
```

**Output**:

```
TASK     MIN_REM   DT                  EXPIRATION      
----- ----------   -----------------   -----------------
Task1       1800   27-10-16 09:45 AM   01-11-16 03:45 PM
Task2       3400   28-10-16 09:45 AM   08-11-16 10:25 AM
Task3        400   29-10-16 03:45 AM   31-10-16 03:40 PM
Task4        180   30-10-16 09:45 AM   31-10-16 12:00 PM
Task5       8400   31-10-16 09:45 PM   24-11-16 01:00 PM
Task6       5000   01-11-16 05:00 PM   16-11-16 12:20 PM
Task7          0   01-12-16 05:00 PM   01-12-16 05:00 PM

 7 rows selected
```